# Bigquery Sql not giving the expected result

Tags: database, google-bigquery, visualization, data-analysis, data-anomalies

it keeps bringing this statement
'SELECT list expression references column stn which is neither grouped nor aggregated'

This is the query

SELECT
stn,
date,
AVG(TEMP),
FROM
'bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020'
WHERE
stn="725030" OR stn="744860"
AND date BETWEEN'2020-7-1'AND '2020-7-30'

Tried to run a query and was expecting a result but could not get it

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the data. As soon as an aggregation function, such as `AVG` is used, the other columns need to be listed after the `group by`.

```sql
SELECT
  stn,
  date,
  AVG(TEMP),
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020`
WHERE
  stn="725030"
  OR stn="744860"
  AND date BETWEEN'2020-7-1'AND '2020-7-30'
GROUP BY 1,2   # 1st and 2nd column are dimension for the AVG-function
```

Answer (score 1):

an avg function requires a group by.

You should group by the first 2 columns in order to find an avg for the same stn/date
example of group query

```
SELECT stn, date, AVG(TEMP) 
FROM 'bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2020' 
WHERE stn="725030" OR stn="744860" AND date BETWEEN'2020-7-1'AND '2020-7-30'
group by 1,2
```